# How can i compare user name and password in a where clause in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

How can i compare user name and password in a where clause in SQLite ?

```
Cursor cur= db.query("accountTable",
  new String[]{"colProject"},"colName" +" = ?",
  new String[]{uname} AND "colPass" +" = ?",
  new String[]{pass}, null, null, null);
```

i am using the given query but there is error of syntax.

Comment: Did you intend to have quotes around `colProject`, but not around `uname` and `pass` in your in your String[] declarations?

Comment: What language do you use? This looks like Java but maybe you could add some information.

Comment: @Ticho: It's the android API.

Answer (score 2):

You have minced up all the arguments into a bit of a mess there! Try this instead:

```
Cursor cur = db.query("accountTable",    // Where are we looking?
        new String[]{ "colProject" },    // What do we want back?
        "colName = ? AND colPass = ?",   // What are we matching?
        new String[]{ uname, pass },     // What to put in the "holes"?
        null, null, null);               // Everything else default...
```